# Why std::bind can be assigned to argument-mismatched std::function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, bind, std

I have code as follows:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void F(int x) {
  cout << x << endl;
}
int main() {
  std::function<void(int)> f1 = std::bind(F, std::placeholders::_1);
  f1(100);  // This works, will print 100.

  int x = 0;
  std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(F, x);
  f2();  // This works, will print 0.

  std::function<void(int)> f3 = std::bind(F, x);
  f3(200);  // BUT WHY THIS WORKS?????? It prints 0.
  return 0;
}
```

My compiler info is:
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: cppreference says (on the topic of `operator()` for the return value of `std::bind`): *If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to g() are not matched by any placeholders stored in g, the unused arguments are evaluated and discarded.*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is correct behavior.

`std::bind` needs this *looseness* to fit its own specification.

Consider `std::placeholders`, which is used to mark parameters that are passed through to the bound function.

```
using std::placeholders;
std::function<void(int)> f2 = std::bind( F, _1 );
//  Parameter 1 is passed to                ^^
//  the bound function.

f2(7); // The int 7 is passed on to F
```

Similarly, there is `_2` for the second parameter, `_3` for the third, and so on.

That brings up an interesting question.  How should this function object behave?

```
auto f3 = std::bind( F, _3 );
```

As you might imagine, it follows its own promise to pass the third parameter to F.  Which means it does nothing to the first two parameters.

```
f3(10, 20, 30); // The int 30 is passed on to F. The rest?  Ignored.
```

So this is expected behavior, and possibly the only "feature" that `std::bind` holds over lambdas, even in C++14 and C++17.

**The object produced by `std::bind` is designed to accept and ignore any extraneous parameters.**

Comment: To be sure. This is also correct ? `std::function<void(int)> f3 = std::bind(F);`

Comment: @DawidDrozd not if `F` has any parameters, the bind has to provide them