# How to replace std::bind with lambda within steady_timer::async_wait

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8c88e88bd982190)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <functional>

class printer
{
public:
  printer(boost::asio::io_context& io)
    : timer_(io, boost::asio::chrono::seconds(1))
  {
    timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&printer::print, this));
    // timer_.async_wait([this]() {
    //     print();
    // });
  }

  void print()
  { 
      std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  }

private:
  boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
};

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_context io;
  printer p(io);
  io.run();

  return 0;
}
```

I tried to replace the following line:

```
timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&printer::print, this));
```

with

```
 timer_.async_wait([this]() {
     print();
 });
```

But it failed and the compiler reports the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'printer::printer(boost::asio::io_context&)':
main.cpp:12:22: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock>::async_wait(printer::printer(boost::asio::io_context&)::<lambda()>)'
   12 |     timer_.async_wait([this]() {
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
   13 |         print();
      |         ~~~~~~~~      
   14 |     });
      |     ~~
```

**Question**> What is the correct way to rewrite the std::bind with lambda expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda doesn't have the required signature.

Based the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WaitHandler.html), the callback takes a `const boost::system::error_code&` argument.  `std::bind` lets you be a bit looser in the function signature ([Why std::bind can be assigned to argument-mismatched std::function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159140/why-stdbind-can-be-assigned-to-argument-mismatched-stdfunction)), but lambdas need to be an exact match.

The following code seems to work for me

```
    timer_.async_wait([this](auto const &ec) {
        print();
    });
```

Comment: "*Your lambda doesn't have the required signature*" - neither does `print()` when it was being used with `std::bind()`, so the original code shouldn't have worked, either. It would have compiled, but invoked undefined behavior at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That threw me off too, but the answer I linked seems to suggest `std::bind` doesn't care about extra arguments.  That was new to me until just now.